# How to use shell commands inside mathematica

Tags: command-line

I want to know how to use simple shell commands inside mathematica. For example:
I want to set the current directory as the NotebookDirectory using shell command PWD.
Something like

```
SetDirectory[$PWD]
```

I saw there are some commands like

```
Run["!echo $PWD"]
```

but how to use that inside SetDirectory.

Comment: Is this [RunProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) of some help?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `Directory[]`?  The current directory of the shell process may in principle not be the same as that of Mathematica.

Comment: @Louis RunProcess won't work.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can use Directory[] but that is not what I want. I want to know how to incorporate the shell (bash) commands into mathematica if it is possible.

Comment: The RunProcess documentation has multiple examples along this line.  Did you read them before deciding that "it won't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I am new in mathematica. I tried to work out using RunProcess but unsuccessful/ seems to be much complicated.

Comment: I tried 

    string=RunProcess["! echo $PWD"];
    string >> out;

Comment: be aware of `NotebookDirectory[]`

Comment: @george2079 , I do know this command and I use this also. But my query is a bit different.

Comment: do not use the ! with runprocess. Also you really do need to supply arguments as a list of strings as shown in the examples.

Comment: Look under "Scope" on the documentation page, first example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this works for me under linux:

```
 SetDirectory[StringDrop[RunProcess["pwd","StandardOutput"],-1]]
```

( `StringDrop` drops a trailing "\n" )

Note the directory returned is the same as returned by `Directory[]` (even if you change it with `SetDirectory` ), which tells us `RunProcess` runs in an environment set up by mathematica.

Edit This:

```
 SetDirectory[StringDrop[RunProcess[{"printenv","PWD"},"StandardOutput"],-1]]
```

gives the directory from which I start mathematica if started from a shell prompt.
(Even if previously changed by `SetDirectory`).  This directory is also available as `$InitialDirectory`.

I should add I also messed with this on a windows machine with no luck.  On windows `Directory[]` does not return the startup directory when starting from a command prompt, and `RunProcess` evidently can not run intrinsic dos shell commands like dir, chdir, etc.

```
 RunProcess[{"cmd", "/C", "set"}]
```

or

```
 RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "set\nexit\n"]
```

gets us environment variables, but nothing that looks like the startup directory.
`$InitialDirectory` doesn't report what we want either on windows.
(I guess this explains why windows apps always try to "save as" in some random place that you don't want)